# Naming decision: "Create it if it doesn't exist" in one word

Tags: naming

#### Exact duplicate of

- [Function name for creating something if it's not there yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238386/function-name-for-creating-something-if-its-not-there-yet)

I have a function which checks if a certain thing exists, and if not, creates it. What would be a good word for it? Right now I'm using "maintain", so the function is called `maintain_buffer_on_path`, but I think that "maintain" is misleading. Can you think of a better one-word name?

Comment: See here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238386/function-name-for-creating-something-if-its-not-there-yet

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228758/good-name-for-a-method-that-adds-to-a-container-if-not-aleady-there

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually use `ensure` for this.

Answer (score 10):

`EnsureExists` (or simpler `Ensure`) seems to be some kind of a convention.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the word vivify to refer to this.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `summon` for this before.